# My bool decimal toggle is supposed to enable/disable hexadecimal output, but it only seems the work for a first toggle, why is that?

Tags: c++

The decimal toggle is supposed to enable/disable hexadecimal output of my stack based calculator when the input is `x`. If you're wondering about the execute function; when if gets `x` as an input it just sets status to true in order to repeat the loop. The problem is, when I execute this, the toggle work once only, I can switch to hexadecimal output, but I can switch back to decimal output. Can you please help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Calculator.h>
#include <Input.h>
#include <IStack.h>
#include <StackSeq.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Calculator TheCalculator;
    bool status;
    bool decimal=true;
    do
    {
        //Prompt for input
        cout<<">";
        Input input;
        if (input.Token()=='x') decimal=!decimal;
        status=TheCalculator.Execute (input);
        if (status)
        {
            for(StackSeq seq     (TheCalculator.GetStack());!seq.AtEnd();seq.Advance())
            {
                if (decimal) cout<<"    "<<seq.GetNum()<<endl;
                else cout<<hex<<"    "<<seq.GetNum()<<endl;
            }
        }
    } while (status);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hex` iomanipulator will stay in effect until it is changed with something like `dec`.  To output your decimal value, use

```
if (decimal) cout<<dec<<"    "<<seq.GetNum()<<endl;
```

Comment: Thanks you soooo much!!